# Operator form $L^2$ space to$L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, definition

Can we have an operator such that it transforms  an element of $L^2$ to $L^1$? Is this a valid question or this is incorrect? We can consider the measure space as finite.

Comment: If the measure space is finite, the formal identity from $L_2$ to $L_1$ is continuous. But, what do you mean by "on defined conditions"?

Comment: I expected the operator to be valid only on certain conditions only, I will remove it now. By the way I got this idea from your answer to my earlier question. I am very much interested to learn about such operators.

Comment: There are a plenty of operators from $L^2$ to $L^1$, for example, every $f\in L^2$ defines such an operator via multiplication.

Comment: @MaoWao, I am kind of interested of it;s characteristic, specially spectral.

Comment: Take $L^2\ni f\to f^2\in L^1$

Comment: @Mitsos would you please assist to find the the proof of the above? I was looking for some fixed operator, at least the proof of the above may give me insight.

Comment: @Creator $f\in L^2$ means $\int |f|^2 <\infty$ and $g\in L^1$ means $\int |g|<\infty$. We have that $\int |f^2| =\int |f|^2 <\infty$.

Comment: @Mitsos: If you want to talk about spectral properties, you have to specify the topologies on $L^1$ and $L^2$. Do you want to view operators $L^2\to L^1$ as densely defined operators on $L^1$?

Comment: @MaoWao, yes, I am looking for densely defined operators on $L^1$